# How to Automate a Text field in an Iframe Using Robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I am Trying to Automate the Text fields In  Iframes Using Robotframework-Selenium2library, But I am Facing issue like Element is not found in below Script.

```
*** TestCases ***    
Iframe
        Select Frame    xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]
        Input Text  xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]  iframes
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeXxJ.png)

Comment: Please provide some more information and the error message. You can edit your question.

Comment: Share relevant HTML too.

Comment: which element is it not finding? Can you please show the exact error message?

Comment: I Edit the question and Attached the Log file.Please give any solution on it..